# How can I edit a post?

Tags: support, bug, editing

Is it an intended feature of the new interface that nobody can edit a post if an edit of that post is stuck in the review queue awaiting enough votes for approval or rejection?

Whether feature or bug, it is extraordinarily annoying. It is also new with the new site design. It did not used to happen like this!

There are two cases:

## Case 1

This is by far the most annoying: it prevents me from editing my own post!

Sometimes, if I edit a post, the system simultaneously logs me out and adds the edit to the review queue, marking it as submitted by an anonymous user. After logging back in, I can approve the edit but obviously that's just one vote in its favour.

In the past, I've just edited the question again, the system has recognised me as logged in, and the edit has taken.

Now, however, if I click on `edit`, I get immediately pushed to the review queue even if I've already approved the edit, and told I can't approve again. Obviously that makes sense - I can only vote once. But I now cannot edit the post at all until, presumably, the edit has garnered enough votes to be approved or rejected.

Moreover, I assume this will happen to anybody else who tries to edit the post as well.

Here is the question I unsuccessfully edited: [How to put the Solarized Theme in TexMaker Editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256423/how-to-put-the-solarized-theme-in-texmaker-editor?noredirect=1#comment620522_256423).

[The Jul 22 edit is a previous edit by me. My unsuccessful edit of Aug 4 is not recognised as being mine.]

Note that this also means that I can immediately see - cannot, in fact, avoid seeing - which users approve or reject my edits. Is this intended?

## Case 2

It is impossible to improve the formatting, wording or content of a post with an edit pending approval or rejection. For example, I cannot currently tidy up the English in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267292/inserting-code-using-listings-goes-off-page) because another user has edited it, but the edit has not yet been approved or rejected. Since the other user is probably the OP in this case, this is probably a function of the standard dual-account problem. But the general issue is independent.

Note that this is less frustrating because, heck, it is somebody else's question and I can easily decide not to take much of an interest. Not great if it is your question, maybe, but not terribly annoying for me.

[But arguably my taking no interest is really the best thing that could happen to your question. So certainly the balance of benefits to costs may weigh on the side of the new feature in this case....]

Side issue: when the review queue comes up it is now in one of those annoying floating window things. Worse still, depending where I am on the page, most of the floaty thing may be off screen. In this case, only about the bottom cm or so was actually visible. So there's just a dimmed screen with a white strip at the top. It took me some time to recognise this as the review queue.

Comment: This is a strange issue. It never happened to me (so far)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I suspect it is part of the improved navigation. (The editing bit - not the logging-me-out bit. The logging-me-out mid-edit bit is not new.)

Comment: 'improved' navigation? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer So they say.

Comment: Anything new here?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Nope. Nothing I know of. I'm assuming it is a bug?